# navbar using a checkbox

Tags: html, css, nav

trying to create a Nav-drawer that opens when a checkbox is checked, all great but the opening part is where am stuck at

HTML

```
<div class="leftside">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
    <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars icon navburger"></i>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="nav-items">
     ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-items{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -100%;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 10001;
    background-color: #fff;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: all .5s;
}
#check{
    display: none;
}
#check:checked ~ .nav-items {
    left: 0;
}
```

I believe that its a problem in the last css code of #check but i cant figure out why.

Comment: can you create a working example here?:
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ritchie-01rxu?file=/index.html
with your nav items please

Comment: btw, i believe that your problem is your not using javascript. i am not 100% sure but i think you cant or you shouldn't use a css `#check:checked ~ ul` like a if condition to change the value of a other selector.

Comment: actually, the example that you have sent is my current problem, and i just want to make left set to zero when a user clicks a checkbox label so why cant i just use :checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#check:checked ~ ul{
    left: 0;
}
```

will not do a manipulating at

```css
.nav-items{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -100%; <------------
    display: flex;
    z-index: 10001;
    background-color: #fff;
    flex-direction: column;
```

your ref. is on

```css
#check
```

that's two different selectors.
so you are doing a `left: 0`
only at `#check`, **not** at `.nav-items`

UPDATE:
this is how i would do this with JS
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ritchie-01rxu?file=/index.html:0-1383

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .nav-items {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        left: -100%;
        z-index: 10001;
        background-color: #fff;
        flex-direction: column;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }
      #check:checked ~ ul {
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="leftside">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" />
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars icon navburger"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-items">
      <ul>
        <li>lala</li>
        <li>lala</li>
        <li>lala</li>
        <li>lala</li>
        <li>lala</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
      const checkbox = document.querySelector("#check");
      const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-items");
      checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
        console.log(checkbox.checked);
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          nav.style.left = "0";
        } else {
          nav.style.left = "-100%";
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah nvm am willing to do it at .nav-items, it have been set to that by mistake :), but still both will give the same problem.

Comment: @rector check my answer pls. maybe this is what you wanted to do, if so, i will explain how i did this if in case you don't know

Comment: yeah, thank you for that. using javascript was also kept in mind but i told myself i may find a faster css method. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the checkbox navigation hack works but I've got a weird issue and it's more evident on smaller touch devices.

Even with the navigation menu in closed state you can click on the links which are in the background (done with z-index).

You will also find that the links are clickable on the left of the page, beside the heading, thats where the text slide in from for the menu.

If anyone you have a fix to this or know how to solve this please reply. Thank you.

https://codepen.io/thompsongeorge/pen/JjeRQxW

```
since the code is too large I haven't pasted it.
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34586845)